# Mercurial commands for merging both conflicting and non-conflicting changes

Tags: merge, mercurial

Mercurial 3.4.1 on Mac Yosemite (10.10.5) here. I don't know why I find `hg` so confusing. I cloned a repo several weeks ago and have been pecking away at it here and there. I'm now ready to push all my changes to the remote `hg` server but several other developers have made changes (both conflicting and non-conflicting) in the meantime. This project uses pure mainline development (no branching) against `default`.

I ran `hg add .` and then `hg commit -m "Fixing x, y and z."`, and now I need to merge my local `default` HEAD with the `default` HEAD on the remote/origin `hg` server. So I need:

- **Exact** command(s) that will automatically merge all non-conflicting changes; and
- **Exact** command(s) that will pop open an editor and allow me to view and manually merge conflicting changes

Not sure that it makes a difference, but a lot of my changes also refactored the basic project structure (deleted/renamed/moved both source files and directories). So these changes should be pretty significant.

Reading the [`hg merge` doc](https://selenic.com/hg/help/merge), I'm now even more confused than before! No where does that doc specify how to explicitly merge my local `default` HEAD with the remote `default` HEAD. Furthermore, the doc mentions:

> "hg resolve" must be used to resolve unresolved files.

What are unresolved files?!? Do I have to run this command *prior* to `hg merge`? How does it affect/interact with the merging process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hg merge` command merges the files in the current working directory with the changes in the revision specified by the `-r` argument (if the current working directory is the checkout of a head of a branch and the branch has exactly one other head, then the other revision to merge with is inferred automatically). The result of the merge can then be committed and (upon commit) becomes a child revision of these two revisions. What you usually do is therefore:

```
hg update ORIGINAL_REVISION
hg merge -r NEW_REVISION
```

Both `ORIGINAL_REVISION` and `NEW_REVISION` can be specified as described in `hg help revisions` or `hg help revsets`.

The result of `hg merge` will be the result of combining the changes in `NEW_REVISION` with `ORIGINAL_REVISION`. Whenever Mercurial can combine the changes without any apparent conflicts, it will do that. Note that `hg merge` will not commit the combined changes, but only update the working directory; committing them to create a merge commit is a separate step.

What happens if there is a conflict? If there is a merge tool available (Mercurial will try to be smart about available merge tools and select one from a list it knows about if one is available, but you may have to specify it explicitly, e.g. via the `--tool` option; see `hg help mergetools` for more details), this tool will be started and you can resolve the conflict in there. If no tool from its list is available and you haven't specified one (via your `.hgrc`, the `HGMERGE` environment variable, or the `--tool` option), Mercurial will fall back to its internal conflict resolution tool (equivalent to `--tool :merge`), which will simply add conflict markers to the file that can then be resolved either manually inside your editor of choice or with a tool that knows how to handle such conflict markers.

You can use `hg resolve` to review and update the list of files with conflicts. Specifically, `hg resolve -l` will list the files that had conflicts, prefixed by `R` if the conflict has been resolved (e.g. by a merge tool or because you marked it as resolved) or `U` if the conflict remains unresolved. You can use `hg resolve -m FILE` to mark `FILE` as resolved or `hg resolved -u FILE` to mark it as unresolved (you can also provide a list of files or `-a` to mark all files). You can use `hg resolve --tool TOOL FILE` or `hg resolve FILE` to redo the merge for a specific file.

Once `hg resolve -l` shows no more unresolved conflicts, you can then commit the merge.

If at any point during the merge your working directory ends up in a state that you cannot seem to recover from, `hg update -C` will abort the merge and undo the entire merge (careful: you will lose any merging resolutions that you have done so far).

If (as you indicated) you also renamed or deleted files, additional effort may be necessary. Normally, you should use `hg mv` to rename files, `hg cp` to copy them, and `hg rm` or `hg forget` to remove them. This will inform `hg merge` what their common ancestor is and allows changes from both branches to the same file to be combined, even if both branches have them ending up in different files. If you didn't do that, you can use `hg addremove -s PERCENTAGE` to try and let Mercurial smartly discover renames and copies (mind you, this still has to be done before you commit or merge the changes). The `-s`/`--similarity` argument is a percentage (by default 100) that indicates how similar files have to be in order to be seen as a rename/copy of one another. You can use `-n` or `--dry-run` to just have `hg addremove` list what it would do without actually doing it.

Answer (score 1):

A merge is *always* a local operation where you merge one revision into another from another branch or head.

When you used the internal merge tool, it will add conflict markers to the places where it needs internal intervention. You usually visit those files, fix the conflict and then mark the conflicts resolved within those file(s) explicitly by using `hg resolve --mark FILE`. You cannot commit the merge before not all those merge conflicts have been marked as handled. You can mark all conflicts as handled at once: `hg resolve --mark --all` - but be sure that you actually handled all merge conflicts or your files will be committed with merge conflict indicators remaining which likely is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @planetmaker (+1) - a few followups if you don't mind. It sounds like you're saying that I need to: (1) run `hg merge`, which will auto-merge non-conflicting changes and mark conflicting changes with markers (**yes??**). Then (2) I need to open my revision in a diff tool, which will then visualize those markers (**yes??**). And finally, (3) once I manually merge and mark all those conflicts as "resolved", I should be able to do an `hg push` (**yes??**). Thanks for any clarifications/confirmations here!

Comment: whatever merge tool you configured, they will merge non-conflicting changes just fine (or they'd be bad tools). If you use the internal merge, search your project for the merge markers and change the code places such that they're ok. Then mark everything resolved and `commit`. Push has nothing to do with a merge.

Comment: Thanks again @planetmaker (+1) - I'm really not trying to be difficult here, but I think your answers are based on some "assumed knowledge" that I just don't (at this point) have. Let's say I want to use KDiff3. **Do I run `hg merge` and *then* open KDiff3, or do I just open KDiff3 and run the merge from inside of it?**

Comment: iff correctly configured, kdiff3 will open automatically a window with the file where you can solve the conflict on-the-fly and save the corrected source when a merge conflict occurs during the merge.